# Градиентный график в matplotlib

Tags: python, графика, numpy, matplotlib

Всем здравствуйте!

Есть необходимость построить градиентный график для отображения результатов вычисления точности геодезической широты.

Моя программа циклично высчитывает точность вычисления широты для заданной высоты (в диапазоне высот от -1км до 10км с шагом в 1км для всех широт о -90 до +90 с шагом 0.16 градусов магическим образом вычисляется точность)

В результате я получаю список, который содержит 1125 чисел - точность вычисления каждой i-ой широты при **конкретной высоте**.

В результате я имею 11 таких списков. (на каждую из высот)

Есть необходимость отобразить это на градиентном графике, сделать это можно при помощи matplotlib, но я не понимаю, как. Читал документацию и смотрел примеры скрипта на сайте этой библиотеки, но не понимаю, как это работает.

Должно быть как на скрине, только по оси У - высоты от -1км, до 10км, по оси Х - широты от -90 до +90, а по оси Z(столбик справа) - как раз точности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот вырезка из скрипта для pcolormesh с их офф сайта:

```
import numpy as np

dx, dy = 0.05, 0.05

y, x = np.mgrid[slice(1, 5 + dy, dy),
                slice(1, 5 + dx, dx)]

z = np.sin(x)**10 + np.cos(10 + y*x) * np.cos(x)
```

Но я никак не могу понять, что происходит с этими переменными - x,y,z.
При этом что делает сам mgrid я в принципе понимаю, но что происходит внутри него в этом куске кода - нет. **(с этим уже разобрался)**

Соответсвенно, не понимая, как работает этот пример, я не могу разобраться, как мне решить уже мою задачу.

P.S. Если получилось очень сумбурно, непонятно или ещё что-то такое - не кидайтесь тапками, пожалуйста) Я студент ещё и только учусь, а с питоном вообще недавно познакомился, но уже нужно решать такие вопросы

P.S.2 Немного покопавшись, (спасибо первому ответу под этим вопросом) я более менее разобрался, что да как. Даже получилось построить график.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Однако на градиентный он не похож, как будто развёрнут вертикально. При этом полученные числовые значения в общем и целом правильные, и график я должен получить примерно такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
то есть проблема похоже в отрисовке этого самого графика, потому что мои численные значения и эталон очень похожи (достаточно посмотреть на порядок чисел по оси Z, чтобы убедиться). Но я не понимаю, почему мой так выходит. Вот фрагмент кода:

```
y, x = np.mgrid[-1000:10000:1000, -0.16:89.84:0.16]

z = np.array(lst_b)

levels = MaxNLocator(nbins=200).tick_values(z.min(), z.max())

cmap = plt.get_cmap('PiYG')

norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()

im = ax0.contourf(x, y, z, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax0)

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

**прим.** `lst_b` - это список из 11 списков, каждый из которых содержит нужные мне числа.

Answer (score 2):

Для того чтобы нарисовать 3D график нам нужна соответствующая 3D матрица.

Функция [np.mgrid[]](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) позволяет создать равномерные 2D решетки координат для `X` и `Y` из срезов.

Проще всего понять это на маленьком примере:

```
In [49]: x, y = np.mgrid[0.0:1.5:0.5, 0.0:1.5:0.5]

In [50]: x
Out[50]:
array([[0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.5, 0.5, 0.5],
       [1. , 1. , 1. ]])

In [51]: y
Out[51]:
array([[0. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 1. ],
       [0. , 0.5, 1. ]])
```

`y` - транспонированый `x` если задать одинаковые срезы при вызове `np.mgrid[]`

```
In [52]: x.T == y
Out[52]:
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])
```